# How do I find a list of PDB structures bound to a peptide inhibitor or peptide-like inhibitor?

Tags: pdb

I looked up existing databases but ones like [iPPI-DB](http://www.ippidb.cdithem.fr/) or [enter link description here](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/merops/inhibitors/) either provide non-peptide inhibitors or only sequences. I need structures of proteins bound to other proteins, the latter of which is an inhibitor of the former, and the complex has a structure deposited in the PDB database. Here's an example: [PDB:3U1J](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/3U1J)

In case there is no existing database in literature, it'd be great even if I can screen for such PDB entries using some code, but I can't come up with an algorithm for it. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site @simple_dozer! I'm not sure if there is a code name to know if a protein is an inhibitor, but you can start by subsetting all the structures with at least two genes

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to screen the PDB database is *Advanced Search* from either [RCSB](http://www.rcsb.org/) or [PDBe](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/).

Since you need entries with 2+ proteins you can set the number of protein chains to at least 2 in the RCSB search.  Or you can select "protein/protein complex" in *Assembly composition* in the PDBe search.

It's less clear how to search for inhibitors. If you'd look for the "inhibitor" word in the molecule names you'd get (together with the previous criterium) 1200+ entries.

[image: RCSB advanced search]